# Will vuex work properly with generic mutations that don't reference `state`?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I’m using vuex with a tree of data. It's reactive and works well because we have a corresponding tree of components. Since the structure is a tree, it’s common to want to mutate a deeply nested child object. The easy way to implement that is with a mutation that accepts the child in its payload:

```
removeLeaf(state, { child, leaf }) {
  child.children = child.children.filter((i: any) => i !== leaf);
  state = state; // silence warning
},
```

A different way would be to change the mutation to work like this:

```
removeLeaf(state, { child_, leaf }) {
  let child = searchForChild(state, child_);
  child.children = child.children.filter((i: any) => i !== leaf);
},
```

I’m happy with the first way. Are there any drawbacks to writing mutations that modify a child object of state by using payload instead of the state parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'll work properly.

**Vue's and Vuex's reactivity system is based on Javascript [Getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [Setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).**

If you console.log the `state` in any mutation, you will see something like this:

[image]

The `get` and `set` is the getter and setter of your Vuex States.

Without the setter, Vue's reactivity system likely wouldn't work.

Try console.log `state` and `child` in your mutation. You will likely see that  the `child` **doesn't contain setter**.

If the setter is not there, Vue wouldn't know that you have updated the state of `child`, and you will likely have reactivity problem.

Comment: The reactivity appears to be working well. I'll check the logs.